# Python: Assign letter and number to a variable without spaces

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I was wondering. how can I get the output like this, and store it in to a string?

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(0,3):
    if i > 0:
        print("G",i,sep="")
```

output:

```
G1
G2
```

I was wondering how I can store the values into a string? (for-loop)

Comment: You want to store the values like they are printed ?

Comment: append whatever you are printing in a for loop!

Comment: `s = 'G{}'.format(i)`

Comment: `print()` is used to display text on screen, not to create value and store in variable.

Answer (score 1):

Following code can work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
st = ""
for i in range(0,3):
    if i > 0:
        print("G",i,sep="")
        st += "G"+str(i)+"\n"
print (st)
```

which shall give you the following output:

[image]